# Git not adding files in subdirectories

Tags: git

I’m having trouble adding files within two subdirectories using `git add .`

Here is my global .gitignore in the parent directory:

```
.vs/
*.sdf
*.opensdf
```

The files I’d like to stage are all .cs files, so .gitignore cannot be the cause of this.

The local .gitignore to each subdirectory also do not contain `*.cs` that could cause this.

After running `git add .` followed by `git status` the output is:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
modified: subdirectory1 (modified content)
modified: subdirectory2 (modified content)

no changes added to commit (use “git add” and/or “git commit -a”)
```

So `git add .` is doing nothing. I have tried `git add subdirectory1/ subdirectory2/` and this also does nothing.

How can I stage both modified subdirectories from the parent directory?

Comment: `git add .` works fine for me.

Comment: Try `git check-ignore --verbose` on one of the files that you expect to be added just in case.

Comment: `modified: subdirectory1 (modified content)` this suggests that subdirectory1 is a git repository, perhaps a submodule. You cannot make changes to a submodule from the parent repo.

Comment: You’re correct. It is a submodule. Now I am trying to figure out how to create one parent PR consisting of the pushes from the two submodules. Perhaps I will make another post for this.